# Range Slider Using Ruby on Rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Using Ruby on Rails.My Code for slider is as follows:

```
<%= range_field_tag(:sliderRangeRails) %>
```

This gives me slider as follows:

[image: It has only one slider.But i want two slider]

But I want range slider as shown below:

[image]

Which has two sliders and gives two values with `#('something').slider` jquery method.What should be my code in ruby to display the slider as shown in second image.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you're referring to a jQuery UI slider. If you don't already have jquery-ui in your app, you can set it up like this:

Add `gem 'jquery-ui-rails'` to your **Gemfile**

Add `//= require jquery-ui` to **application.js**

Add `*= require jquery-ui` to **application.css**

Run `bundle`

In your view, create a div to hold your slider:

```
<div id="the_slider"></div>
```

Then add a pair of hidden fields to your form for the attributes that are getting the slider data:

```
<%= form_for @thing do |thing_form| %>
    <%= thing_form.hidden_field :data1 %>
    <%= thing_form.hidden_field :data2 %>
    <%= thing_form.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

The last part is your JavaScript, which can go in the view or in a separate **js** file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var slider = $("#the_slider").slider({
        range: true,
        min: 200,
        max: 500,
        values: [250, 450],
        slide: function(event, ui) {
            $("#thing_data1").val(ui.values[0]);
            $("#thing_data2").val(ui.values[1]);
        }
    });
    $("#thing_data1").val(slider.slider("values")[0]);
    $("#thing_data2").val(slider.slider("values")[1]);
});
```

`thing_data1` and `thing_data2` are the `id`'s that `form_for` would give to the `hidden_field`'s in this context. Also, of course, you could do whatever you wanted with the values from the slider in the `slide:` callback function before assigning data to the `hidden_field` `input` `value`'s.

**Edit:** I gave the `hidden_field` `input`'s the initial values from the slider so they'll be submitted by the form if the client does not move one or both of the slider handles.

Comment: Using the above code.I have to submit the form to db.But,I need to capture values as user stops the `slider` everytime.I Wrote the code in HTML.Instead of ruby.But,My code is not showing the slider.Other text in the slider `div` are seen.For my code.I used `stop` event instead of `slide`.event.

Comment: Are you still using the slider within your Rails app? Because if you aren't, you need to source the jQuery UI files in your HTML document.

Comment: I am adding range slider in a partial page.And append the partial page on another page as user selects from a multiple selection dropdown menu. Everything is working fine.But,I cannot see the range slider in my partial view which is rendered in the main page.But,i can see the text in the partial page.I added the jquery-ui in `application.js` and `application.css`.

Comment: Where did you put the JavaScript for the slider?

Comment: It worked with Jquery.I kept the script in my partial page itself.Previously,It is slider not appeared because the script is not compiled at the correct time.

Comment: easy to copy paste! best response ever! +1