# Ruby on Rails - Combine Text Field with Select?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

I want a text field that when the user presses it, appears some possible options, like a dropdown with options (or datalist). Something like this:

[image]

Is there any gem or library that can do this for me? Or is there a good example how to do this properly? I've tried to seach but maybe I'm not making the right question beacause I can't find much stuff...

EDIT:

About my project:

I'm doing a car website, so I need to filter the cars by price, year, kilometers, etc...That's why I need a text field that users can put, for example, their price range but as the same time I want to show some options that they can select too. These options are static, they dont came from any model.

I will then use the :price_start and :price_ending to do a named_scope to filter the data.

Here is my model:

```
create_table "vehicles", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "kms"
  t.integer "power"
  t.string "transmission"
  t.string "fuel"
  t.string "category"
  t.integer "seats"
  t.integer "doors"
  t.string "color"
  t.string "condition"
  t.string "warranty"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.integer "model_id"
  t.integer "manufacturer_id"
  t.float "cc"
  t.string "version"
  t.integer "price"
  t.integer "month"
  t.integer "year"
  t.index ["manufacturer_id"], name: "index_vehicles_on_manufacturer_id"
  t.index ["model_id"], name: "index_vehicles_on_model_id"
end
```

My index:

```
<%= form_tag(filter_vehicles_path, method: 'get') do %>
<h4><strong>

  <span>Fabricante</span>
  <%= collection_select :manufacturer, :manufacturer_id, Manufacturer.joins(:vehicles).uniq, :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "manufacturer_dropdown"} %>

  <span>Modelo</span>
  <%= grouped_collection_select :model, :model_id, Manufacturer.order(:name), :models, :name,  :id, :name, {include_blank: true}, {class: "model_dropdown", data: {models: @models}} %>

  <span>Preço</span>
  <%= select_tag :price_start, options_for_select([ "250 EUR", "500 EUR", "1000 EUR", "2000 EUR", "3000 EUR", "4000 EUR", "5000 EUR", "6000 EUR", "7000 EUR", "8000 EUR", "9000 EUR", "10 000 EUR", "12 000 EUR", "14 000 EUR", "16 000 EUR", "18 000 EUR", "20 000 EUR", "22 000 EUR", "24 000 EUR", "26 000 EUR", "28 000 EUR", "30 000 EUR", "32 000 EUR", "34 000 EUR", "36 000 EUR", "38 000 EUR", "40 000 EUR", "50 000 EUR", "60 000 EUR", "70 000 EUR", "80 000 EUR", "90 000 EUR", "100 000 EUR", "150 000 EUR", "200 000 EUR"]), prompt: "--de--" %>
  <%= select_tag :price_ending, options_for_select([ "250 EUR", "500 EUR", "1000 EUR", "2000 EUR", "3000 EUR", "4000 EUR", "5000 EUR", "6000 EUR", "7000 EUR", "8000 EUR", "9000 EUR", "10 000 EUR", "12 000 EUR", "14 000 EUR", "16 000 EUR", "18 000 EUR", "20 000 EUR", "22 000 EUR", "24 000 EUR", "26 000 EUR", "28 000 EUR", "30 000 EUR", "32 000 EUR", "34 000 EUR", "36 000 EUR", "38 000 EUR", "40 000 EUR", "50 000 EUR", "60 000 EUR", "70 000 EUR", "80 000 EUR", "90 000 EUR", "100 000 EUR", "150 000 EUR", "200 000 EUR"]), prompt: "--até--" %>

  <span>Ano</span>
  <%= select_tag :year_start, options_for_select(["1 990", "1 980", "1 970", "1 960", "1 950", "1 940", "1 930", "1 920", "1 910", "1 900"]), prompt: "--de--" %>
  <%= select_tag :year_start, options_for_select(["1 990", "1 980", "1 970", "1 960", "1 950", "1 940", "1 930", "1 920", "1 910", "1 900"]), prompt: "--até--" %>

  <span>Quilómetros</span>
  <%= select_tag :kms_start, options_for_select([ "5 000 km", "10 000 km", "15 000 km", "20 000 km", "25 000 km", "30 000 km", "35 000 km", "50 000 km", "75 000 km", "100 000 km", "125 000 km", "150 000 km", "200 000 km", "250 000 km", "300 000 km", "350 000 km", "400 000 km", "450 000 km", "500 000 km"]), prompt: "--de--" %>
  <%= select_tag :kms_end, options_for_select([ "5 000 km", "10 000 km", "15 000 km", "20 000 km", "25 000 km", "30 000 km", "35 000 km", "50 000 km", "75 000 km", "100 000 km", "125 000 km", "150 000 km", "200 000 km", "250 000 km", "300 000 km", "350 000 km", "400 000 km", "450 000 km", "500 000 km"]), prompt: "--até--" %>

  <%= submit_tag "Pesquisar" %>
</strong></h4>
```

I will appreciate your help. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add more details about how your models, controllers, form looks like etc. 
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#select-boxes-for-dealing-with-models

Comment: @Proz1g Which data type of this attribute in your database? Does it foreign key or string? Do you look at [select2-rails](https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails) ?

Comment: Hi! I updated my description. Hope it will help you.

@cnnr I did look, but I think its not quite what I want, because I want the user to input text that may not be in the list.

Comment: @Proz1g It's better to use range slider for this search. Take a look to this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33751022/range-slider-using-ruby-on-rails

Comment: @cnnr thank you. I will look into ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're just looking for a enhanced `<select>`

https://select2.org should work, specially the tagging option:

https://select2.org/tagging

If you want to use a gem to integrate it, use: https://github.com/argerim/select2-rails